# Filter and search option in Moodle activity module

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

In my very simple new `activity` `module` in `Moodle` I need to add `filter` and `search` options for the `table` with users and the columns with user data.

We have two tabs `Userlist` and `Add`. 
In the first tab we have table, which shows `username` `timepickedup` `timereturn` `cartype` `city` `status`. And lists the userdata bellow these columns. 
The code is as follows:

```
$rows = carhiring_users($cm->id);

foreach ($rows as $carpicker) {
    $data = array();
    $user = carhiring_get_user($carpicker->userid);
    $data[] = $carpicker->cartype;
    $data[] = date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($carpicker->datepick));
    $data[] = date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($carpicker->datereturn));
    $data[] = $user->firstname . " " . $user->lastname;
    $data[] = $carpicker->city;
    $datetime1 = strtotime($carpicker->datepick);
    $datetime2 = strtotime($carpicker->datereturn);
    $interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
    $data[] = max(1, floor($interval/(60*60*24))) . get_string('carhiring_days', 'carhiring');
    switch ($carpicker->carhiring_status) {
            case 1:
                $carhiring_status = get_string('booked', 'carhiring');
                break;
            case 2:
                $carhiring_status = get_string('bookedbutdamaged', 'carhiring');
                break;
            case 3:
                $carhiring_status = get_string('returned', 'carhiring');
                break;
    }
    $data[] = $carhiring_status;
    $table->add_data($data);
}
```

We add users trough the second tab `Add`, where we can choose the user from the users in the Moodle site and `manually` `add` the rest of `custom data`.

I didn't find any `search` or `filter` `forms` for developers in `Moodle`. How should such `form` be structured in order to work in `Moodle`? If it is possible, I need to put it above the table, not in separate tab.